# unable to Report on LiveChatTranscriptEvent

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, custom-report-type, chat

We want to report on LiveChatTranscriptEvent object to basically see how many transfers are happening.
The Report type is not shown up in Standard/Custom Report Types.

Also, where/how can we query the Message(Optional) set during Chat Transfer Request by an Agent as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_transfer_chat_requests.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

1. The primary object to report on would be "LiveChatTranscript" rather than "LiveChatTranscriptEvent"
2. The secondary object "LiveChatTranscriptEvent" can then be linked as needed
3. Build a report on above report type and group by required fields